# dynamic pivote table

Tags: sql, pivot-table, sql-server-2017

```
DECLARE @tname VARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @tname=''
 SELECT @tname=@tname+convert(varchar,tcode)+',' FROM Table_maintenancereport
 GROUP BY tcode
 SET @tname=LEFT(@tname,LEN(@tname)-1)

    exec('
    select *
    from
    (select SUM(timedurationok)as wt,tcode
    from Table_maintenancereport
    where (svok=1 and need_netok=0) or (svok=1 and netok=1 and need_netok=1)
    group by tcode
    )t
    pivot (sum(wt) 
    for tname in ('+@tname+'))p')
```

when execute this query sql give this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 
>   Incorrect syntax near '2917'.

tcode is int value but i convert this to varchar my be reson of problem this?!

Comment: Make your code safe from injection (yes, you can use object names to inject), and declare your variable lengths. Print the value of your dynamic statement and inspect that, I'm sur eyou'll find the error quickly. If not, post that SQL in your post too. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: @Larnu I have [a post with (almost) the same name](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server-%ef%bb%bf/) in my blog. Didn't know this one, thanks!

Comment: There's a few of them knocking about, @ZoharPeled . I think a few of us just get "fed up" of seeing bad dynamic SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is what you are trying to do.

> First, is get those distinct tcode
>
> Second, is generate sql query string based on your generated columns
>
> Third, is to pivot the sum() of each tcode

```
declare @strsql nvarchar(max);
declare @cols nvarchar(max);

select @cols =
    stuff((select N'],[' + tcode
       from (select distinct tcode 
          from Table_maintenancereport where coalesce(tcode, '') != '') AS t1   
       for xml path('')
    ), 1, 2, '') + N']';
select @cols

set @strsql = N'
        select '+@cols+'
        from
        (select timedurationok as wt, tcode
            from Table_maintenancereport    
            where (svok=1 and need_netok=0) or (svok=1 and netok=1 and need_netok=1)
        )t
        pivot (
            sum(t.wt) 
            for t.tcode in ('+@cols+')
        )p'

exec sp_executesql @strsql
```

Comment: Why `N'],[' + tcode` and not `',' + QUOTENAME(tcode)`?

Comment: @Larnu, its my choice of building the columns.

Comment: But that doesn't mean it's secure, or won't fail if someone has a value with a `]` it it's name (and they do, unfortunately exist), hence my question.

Comment: that is not a variable. why need to secure?

Comment: Because SQL Injection is bad.

Comment: it depends on how you handle dynamic queries. tcode btw is int, how come it will contain brackets.

Comment: It is an `int`, here, but it might not be an `int` in the future. `QUOTENAME` is the right way to properly quote and escape your dynamic object names. `'[' + TableName + ']'` is just as open to injection as a C# application with the statement `cmd = "SELECT * FROM " & txtTableName.Text;`. Just because it's an object name doesn't mean its value can';t be escaped. If `TableName` have the value `sys.objects]; CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN; --` it would inject code.

Comment: based on this scenario. there is no parameter. microsoft would remove dynamic queries if everything is injection.

Comment: *"there is no parameter."* what is `tcode` then? Microsoft aren't going to remove Dynamic SQL, nor should they. What should be removed is code that is open to injection; that is the problem and that's up to the developers of the applications that use SQL. Coding with injection in mind (like here) is why it's still a problem in 2019...

Comment: I never said it wasn't, you've missed my point entirely here... I've tried to explain the perils of SQL injection, but if you don't want to defensively code, that decision is up to you, and I can't force you to do so.

Comment: most questions about pivot is all about generating reports. so im 100% sure theres no user input for this one. im not objecting your concern about sql injection.